# How to place element properily on size of window changed

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a elements where I want to place margin from left is 101px. I did this using below code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if(document.getElementById('minimize-view-id').checked){
         $("#modal-dialog").css("right", "101px");
    }
});
```

This is working fine with full size window but when I minimize window and refresh the element not getting placed properly.

How can I do this.

Comment: Show some html too and check for any `console errors`..

Comment: @Soham Shetty: see my answer and check the demo is, it's fully working...

Answer (score 0):

> **demo:** http://so.devilmaycode.it/how-to-place-element-properily-on-size-of-window-changed/

```
$(function() {
    $(window).resize(function() {
        resize_margin();
    });

    $('#minimize-view-id').on('change', function(){
        console.log($('#minimize-view-id').prop('checked'));
        $.cookie('minimize_view_id', $('#minimize-view-id').prop('checked'));
        resize_margin();
    });

    resize_margin();

    function resize_margin() {
        var right = ($('#minimize-view-id').prop('checked') || $.cookie('minimize_view_id')) === true ? 101 : 0;
        $("#modal-dialog").css("right", right + "px");
    }
});
```

> - **NOTE:** this is the basic code; since you are refreshing the page you need to use something like coockie to track the checkbox otherwise the code will never work correctly.

so a pseudo code con be as follow:

> when the user check the checkbox save it on coockie then when the page
>   load retrive the coockie and apply the css..

in my code i have used this plugin

> - https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

Comment: adding new plugin is not In my hand

Comment: @Soham Shetty: what do you mean? if you can't include it from html page just add the source of the plugin above to the code, it's the only way.

Comment: @Soham Shetty: see the updated source code and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [$( window ).resize()](https://api.jquery.com/resize/) method to make this working. If you want to place the element from a left margin `101px` then you can simply do that as follow:

```
$(function(){
    function doResize() {
       if($('#minimize-view-id').checked){
            $("#modal-dialog").css("right", "101px");
        }
    }
    $(window).resize(function(){
        doResize();
    });
    doResize();
});
```

But if you want to place the element dynamically as per the window width then you can do that by checking [$( window ).width()](http://api.jquery.com/width/) :

```
$(function(){
    function doResize() {
       var widthScreen = $( window ).width();
        if($('#minimize-view-id').checked){
            // Define your right margin as per widthScreen size and then assign that value in below code in place of `101px`
            $("#modal-dialog").css("right", "101px");
        }
    }
    $(window).resize(function(){
        doResize();
    });
    doResize();
});
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: When getting problem when I refresh. not without refreshing. for example when I load page then I have an element whose css(right,101px). when I resize and refresh its not working that element coming left side. same thing happen from minimize to maximize

Comment: If that is the case then put all you codes which are in `$(window).resize()` method in a function and call that in page loads as well.

Comment: Updated my answer, please check!